# TreeNode Html ID in Treeview C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a TreeView but when i click on + button to expand a TreeNode, all the TreeView collapse. I've found the problem, it's because of the HTML ID of the toggle button. 
It's the same for all my TreeNodes.

So do you know how to change TreeNode Html ID in C# ?

PS : My Code

```
public static void LoadCategories()
{
    XmlNodeList nodeCategorie = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Categories");
    //On récupère toutes les catégories.
    tnRoot= new TreeNode("Categories");
    //On créé un élément racine nommé catégories
    // tnRoot.ExpandAll();
    LoadCategory(tnRoot, nodeCategorie.Item(0));
    //On charge les catégories
}

private static void LoadCategory(TreeNode treeNode, XmlNode xmlNode)
{
    TreeNode treeNode1;
    IEnumerator enumerator = xmlNode.GetEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        treeNode1 = new TreeNode(((XmlNode)enumerator.Current).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Libelle").Value, ((XmlNode)enumerator.Current).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Reference").Value, "", "javascript:void(0);", "");
        treeNode1.Expand();
        treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(treeNode1);
        LoadCategory(treeNode1, ((XmlNode)enumerator.Current));
    }
}
```

All My  have id=tViewt0

Comment: show us what you have tried so for to get rid of the issue.

Comment: at least, paste your code...

Comment: There's a reason to get the same ID and the solution is to fix the part which causes this and to try and change it. For starters it might help if you create the new nodes inside the loop. like this: `while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    { TreeNode treeNode1 = new TreeNode(((XmlNode)enumerator.Current)..`

Comment: Thank you ,I've do what you said but it's the same problem.